Как правильно применять EF, миграции, строку подключения при разработки программы и формирования БД и использования уже самим пользователем
Суть: Программа должна использовать PostgreSql, то есть пользователь скачивает отдельно ее, там настраивает значения подключения в основном это пароль. Далее при входе уже в программу использующая бд, нужно ввести данные подключения, которые запишутся в файл конфигурации программы.
Далее как я понял файл конфигурации не должен хранить строку подключения (не безопасно), поэтому записываю лишь Port, Host и название Database так они дефолтные для PostgreSql.
А вот название юзера и его пароль я получаю динамически от ввода пользователя.
Далее мне нужно создать информационную систему(ИС) - просто создание таблиц в бд), для этого:

Пользователь вводит имяЮзера и пароль.
Пользователь нажимает "Создать ИС", из файла конфигурации берутся Host, Port и Database и соединяются с введенными строками имяЮзера и пароля - получаем некую строку подключения.
Нужно проверить есть ли доступ к бд, через: context.Database.CanConnect(), но чтобы проверить нужно переинициализировать строку подключения контекста данных так как изначально пустая.
Если коннект возможен (то есть моя строка подключения совпадает с настройками подключения в postgreSql), то проверить применена ли миграция, если нет то применить миграцию для того чтобы создать таблицы.

Проблемы:

Когда пользователь нажимает "Создать ИС", должна произойти миграция в коде C#, чтобы создались таблицы в БД, но они не создадутся так как нет миграции.

Для того, чтобы создать миграцию в Visual Studio нужна начальная строка подключения, например:
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) =>
     optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Захардкоженная строка");



но ее изначально нет, так как ее я должен получить от ввода пользователя динамически позже когда контекст уже прокинут в класс.
То есть одно зависит от другого. Одна сторона разработчика другая сторона пользователя.
В итоге непонятно как правильно начать разработку программы с применением бд ее формирования при разработке, и работа с бд на уровне пользователя.
Может быть вообще логика должна быть другой для работы и программы и уровня пользователя?


Миграции совершенно не зависят от строки подключения. Другими словами, вы можете их создать в своем проекте с одной строкой подключения, а затем применить эти изменения к другой базе, с другой строкой подключения. Главное, чтоб провайдеры соответствовали. Так что, вы сейчас должны сделать базовое подключение для разработки (без разницы какое и как, главное в коде не храните, используйте "секреты пользователя"), а затем, когда человек введет логин и пароль, вы должны их применить. За применение отвечает .Migrate(); метод.



Строка подключения. Чтоб ее сменить, у EF есть соответствующий метод - .SetConnectionString(), который вы можете вызвать в любой момент и ничего там городить не надо... Ну а где хранить - это уже вопрос довольно обширный и отдельный)


А во как, а то я думал нужны одинаковые параметры подключения, чтобы применить миграцию к бд, попробую, спасибо большое

метод .UseNpgsql() можно без проблем вызывать без строки подключения, с пустыми скобками, когда вам нужна просто миграция. Всё будет работать как вы хотите, сделайте просто это в специальном классе, унаследованном от интерфейса IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<...>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli
